# Load ajax first after a refresh or open the page

Tags: ajax

$(document).ready(function() {

var screen_width = $(window).width();

if (screen_width <= 992) {

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../../pages/sidebar.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#sidebar-container').html(data);
    $('#smallbar-container').html("");
  }
});
```

} else {

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../../pages/smallbar.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#smallbar-container').html(data);
    $('#sidebar-container').html("");
  }
});
```

}
});